# Find least occurring members in the list in C#

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have `list<string>` with random amount of entries (somewhere between 10-500).  and I need to find the value that occurs the least number of time. For example, `list<string> myList`has `100 "a", 50 "b", 2 "c", and 1 "d"`, and I wish to extract "c" and "d". My problem is that I will never know the exact number of each string, and exact name of the string in the list.

For similar analogy, examine the code below:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random r = new Random();                

        int randomNumber = r.Next(5,15);
        int randomRangeOne = r.Next(0,2);
        int randomRangeTwo = r.Next(0,2);

        List<int> randomList = new List<int>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            int x = r.Next(randomNumber - randomRangeOne, randomNumber + randomRangeTwo);
            randomList.Add(x);
        }              
    }
}
```

In this case (in the actual problem, it is random string, not random int), how would I extract least occurring values in the list?

Comment: You want to get least occurring character in strings or least occurring string itself? For example if you have `"hello", "hello", "bye"` the result is `"bye"` or `"y" and "b"`?

Comment: I want the least occuring string itself. In your example, I would want "bye"

Comment: I said for similar analogy, please read the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a simple LINQ

```
var leastOccured = data
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .OrderBy(group => group.Count())
    .Select(x => x.Key)
    .First();
```

You group same strings, sort them by number of each group ascending and take the first one which is the least occurred string in least.

If there can be many strings with same occurrence count you can use the code below

```
var ordered = data
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Select(group => new { group.Key, Count = group.Count() })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Count);

var minOccurrenceCount = ordered.First().Count;

var leastOccurredStrings = ordered 
    .TakeWhile(x => x.Count == minOccurrenceCount)
    .Select(x => x.Key);
```

Comment: @doctor The query should be sorted by descending order since question mentions least occurring needs to be pulled.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get all the values that have the lowest count you could do it in two steps.

```
var lowestCount = stringList.GroupBy(x => x)
                            .Select(x => x.Count())
                            .Min();
var result = stringList.GroupBy(x => x)
                       .Where(x => x.Count() == lowestCount)
                       .Select(x => x.Key);
```

I used the following as the input data:

```
var stringList = new List<string> { "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d","d" };
```

With this input `result` holds "b", "c" ,"d"

Answer (score 1):

Think about the steps logically, how would you do this in real life if you had to do it?

1. Go through the list, putting a tally mark in a box for each item as you find them.
2. Once you are done sort the boxes of tally marks, smallest to biggest.
3. Take the first box and use it.

You can do the same in your program. I feel this is homework so I will not be providing a code example of how to do all three steps but hopefully this will get you on the right track.